# Duplicate Windows Opening

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Visual Studio 2010, Visual Basic .NET

I have a form (frmImages) and I am using it as a class. 
So I create a new form using the frmImages class and I get duplicate windows. 
Not sure why the form is opening twice.

```
Dim images As New frmImages
images.wbImages.Navigate(New Uri("path here"))
images.Text = "Form Title"
images.Show()
```

**UPDATE**
I have determined this issue is due to the mouse down event.  Not sure how to correct this issue though since I need the mouse down event to get the html element based on mouse position. Here are all the parts for this.

```
Private Sub webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles wbContent.DocumentCompleted

        AddHandler wbContent.Document.MouseDown, AddressOf eventSub
End Sub

Private Sub eventSub(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElementEventArgs)

   Dim event_html As New HtmlElementEventHandler(AddressOf wbMouseDown)
   event_html.Invoke(sender, e)

End Sub

Public Sub wbMouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As HtmlElementEventArgs)

    If e.MouseButtonsPressed = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then

        bookmarkElement = wbContent.Document.GetElementFromPoint(e.ClientMousePosition)
        If bookmarkElement.GetAttribute("className").ToString().IndexOf("figureLink ") <> -1 Then
            Dim images As New frmImages
            images.wbImages.Navigate(New Uri(bookmarkElement.GetAttribute("src").ToString()))
            images.Text = "Form Title"
            images.Show()
         End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: How are you triggering the code above to execute?  Does it execute this code twice? (Put a breakpoint in to check this).  Did you somehow have 2 AddHandler statements to wireup the event handler or did you use an 'AddHandler' in combination with a 'Handles' clause - either of these would cause the event handler method to execute twice.

Comment: Check if the event is being called twice. Perhaps the form designer created an event and you manually created one yourself (I once did this)

Comment: Ok so I moved the AddHandler for mouseDown to the end of the load event for my main form, and the issue is resolved. For some reason with it being the WebBrowser Document completed sub, it was getting triggered twice.  Not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

You're opening a new instance of that form. VB doesn't care; you could have a million instances of the form and you could still open more (not a million, but you get my point). When you create a new instance of something it is exactly that, a new instance.

Comment: Ah yeah, fair enough. D'oh!

Comment: So what would be a better way of doing this?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? You said it's opening up new forms, are you trying to get to the already existing form from another form? Some explanation would be helpful.

Comment: I have a form with a WebBrowser control on it, when the user clicks on an image inside the WebBrowser control, it opens in the frmImages form.  Well I needed to allow the user to open as many images as they want.  So I decided to do it the way I have above, and it works, the user can open as many images as they want, but now each image opens two windows.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to prevent it from opening another form

```
Public Class frmImages
    Inherits Form
    Private _instance As frmImages = Nothing
    Private _lock As New Object()

    Private Sub New()
    End Sub


    Public Shared ReadOnly Property Instance() As frmImages
        Get
            If _instance Is Nothing Then
                SyncLock _lock
                    If _instance Is Nothing Then
                        _instance = New frmImages()
                    End If
                End SyncLock
            End If
            Return _instance
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

Comment: I need to be able to open multiple instances of this form.  The problem I am having is each time the form opens, it opens twice. Here is my comment from another answer that might help. -----I have a form with a WebBrowser control on it, when the user clicks on an image inside the WebBrowser control, it opens in the frmImages form. Well I needed to allow the user to open as many images as they want. So I decided to do it the way I have above, and it works, the user can open as many images as they want, but now each image opens two windows.

Comment: ah, ok. Then could you please show me the code of your class frmImages. perhaps your constructor is wrong. Thnx

Comment: I think I just figured it out, but that leads to more problems.  I have a MouseDown event for the WebBrowser Control, and on the MouseDown even it gets the html element from where the mouse is.  I threw a MessageBox in there and the messageBox opens 3 times when the mouse button goes down.  If you don't think this is the problem, I will post the code from frmImages.

Comment: Wow. That sounds like a likely cause. Good luck and post back if it's not fixed.

Comment: Was unable to figure out a workaround for the mousedown event.